# React Native image resize does not result in changed width

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make an location icon in react native `0.53.0`. I created a png of a location marker, which has a size of 114 x 200. Then, I created a component, which has the following render method:

```
render() {
  return (
    <Image
      source={locationImg}
      resizeMode="contain"
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
    />
  );
}
```

I then use this component in a View that has a height of `50px` and a padding of `5px`, meaning the icon will have a height of `40px`. I would then assume that the width of my icon component would be about `23px`, but this is not the case. Despite the `resizeMode="contain"`, the width does not get scaled down, but stays at the original size of the image, `114px`.

[image: the result]

Why doesn't the width scale down as well, and what should I do differently to achieve my wanted result?

Comment: Which version of react-native you are using?

Comment: @PrasunPal I'm using react-native 0.54.0, updated the question to have that info.

Comment: Sorry my bad, it is 0.53.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Image, View } from 'react-native';

import locationImg from '../assets/images/locationImage.png'

// Calculate the ratio to be able to scale the width correctly
const { width: WIDTH, height: HEIGHT } = Image.resolveAssetSource(locationImg);
const RATIO = WIDTH / HEIGHT;

class LocationIcon extends Component {
  // Have the desired width of the component in state
  state = { width: 0 };

  // When receiveing layout, calculate the desired width and update state
  onLayout = event => {
    const { height } = event.nativeEvent.layout;
    this.setState({ width: height * RATIO });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Image
          source={locationImg}
          resizeMode="contain"
          onLayout={this.onLayout}
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            width: this.state.width,  // Update width from state
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default LocationIcon;
```