# react native bringing custom component over the page body component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a custom component `<Header has_image={ true } />` called in an another component and it's working fine for all the pages except the login page where i have to add an image instead of title and push the image from the top of the page to center between the header and the body, the problem is that the image is getting under the page body and i've tried z-indexing with absolute positioning but had no luck

here is my `Header.js` file

```
render () {

    return (

      <LinearGradient start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }} end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }} colors={['#a4d294', '#3ac6f3']} style={ styles.header }>

          <TouchableOpacity style={[ (this.state.user && this.state.user.userType == 'doctor') ? styles.add_button : null ]}>

            { (this.state.user && this.state['userType'] == 'patient') ? <Image source={ require('@media/images/add.png') } style={ styles.add_button } /> : null }

          </TouchableOpacity>

          { this.props.has_image ?
              <Image source={ require('@media/images/header-image.png') } style={ styles.header_image } />
            :
            <Text style={ styles.title }> { this.props.title } </Text>
          }

          <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => this.props.open_drawer() }>

            { this.state.user ? <Image source={ require('@media/images/more.png') } style={ styles.more_button } /> : null }

          </TouchableOpacity>

      </LinearGradient>

    )

  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header : {
    height: 90,
    backgroundColor: '#eee',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  title : {
    color : '#fff',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 20,
    letterSpacing: 3
  },
  header_image : {
    width: 80,
    height: 80,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    marginTop: 90,
    zIndex: 2,
  },
  add_button : {
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
    marginHorizontal: 10
  },
  more_button : {
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
    marginHorizontal: 10
  }
})
```

and here is my component over which i want the image to override

```
<View style={ styles.container }>

        <Header has_image={ true } />

        <ScrollView style={ styles.body } behavior="padding" enabled>

          <View style={ styles.terms_container }>

            <Text style={ styles.terms }>

              The Privacy of the registrants in this program is very important to us. visitors and other registrants will not be able to see any existing personal data

            </Text>

          </View>

            <KeyboardAvoidingView style={ styles.form }>

              { this.state.error ? <Text style={ styles.error }> { this.state.error } </Text> : null }

              <Input
                label='Email Address'
                onChangeText={ (email) => this.setState({ email : email }) }
                keyboardType="email-address"
              />

              <Input
                label='Password'
                onChangeText={ (password) => this.setState({ password : password }) }
                password={ true }
              />

              <Gradient
                disabled={ this.state.loading }
                onPress={ this.login }
                text={ "LOGIN" }
                gradient_style={ styles.button_gradient }
                text_style={ styles.button_text }
                button_style={ styles.button_style }
              />

            </KeyboardAvoidingView>

        </ScrollView>

      </View>
```

the result i want

[image: the result i want]

the result i'm getting

[image: the result i'm getting]

Comment: what happens when you make the image smaller? have you tried increasing the height a little bit or making it 100%?

Comment: nothing changes ..

Comment: after doing a bit of research, i came upon `resizeMode` property 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49087209/react-native-image-resize-does-not-result-in-changed-width
Would adding that property help?

Comment: i already added `resizeMode` it's not working still ..

Comment: Okay. Hmmmm How about adding some padding and/or margins to it?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50511348/react-native-text-gets-vertically-cut-off-for-no-reason

Comment: what does the margin and padding have to do with it ? my problem is overlaying a component over the other so there is a problem in the `zIndex` not working and i asked for an answer why it isn't working here !